# View controller calling a modal view

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, viewcontroller

How can I reliably determine the name of the view controller that called a modal view from within that modal view? The app has a singleton so I was planning to add a view controller there and save the name of the calling view controller. .parentController gives  me the name of the nav controller.

EDIT
I tried a sample project and it did just as mine did so I think maybe were not on the same page.  I appreciate your working with me on this one.  I downloaded a project from

```
http://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/sourcecode/UINavigationControllerWithToolbar.zip?attredirects=0
```

added 2 lines and changed 1 and it demonstrates what I am getting.   It took me all of 5 minutes, if that. In RootViewController.m, info_clicked (line 147), above the last line add,

```
NSLog(@"calling: %@", [[self navigationController] visibleViewController]);
```

then, per your instructions, in the last line change self.navigationController to self.  This controller is what I want to get from the modal.  Then in InfoViewController.m, viewDidLoad (line 35), before the closing curly brace add,

```
NSLog(@"Parent: %@", [self parentViewController]);
```

Change the Base SDK Project Settings to 4.0, Build, open your console and press the Info Button on the bottom.  I'm getting UINavigationController for parentViewController and I want RootViewController.

Comment: parentViewController should work, are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: Please see my comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using `[self.navigationController presentModal...]` instead of `[self presentModal...]`. If you use `self`, `parentViewController` will work.

Comment: Nav based app.  Using [self parentViewController] in modal. Always gives UINavigationController.  Using [[self navigationController] visibleViewController] in the calling class gives me the correct name of it's own view controller.  I want that info from within the modal.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't specifically address your reply: No, I am indeed using [self presentModalViewController:addNavCon animated:YES];  All use a nav controller.

Comment: @Hal Stevens: then... it should work fine! Have you tried making a new project to test with?